# MOTODEV Studio vs. Android Google plugin

Tags: android, ide, comparison

Does anybody have any advice, experience, suggestions? I'm pretty
comfortable with Google plugin - what would make me change to MOTODEV?
Needless to say - I will download and play with it but I'm also
interested in fellow developer's feedback.

Comment: Big, fat warning - there's no built in CVS support in MOTODEV! Bummer, bummer, bummer

Comment: FYI.  CVS and Subversion were added in the January 2010 release.  Git support was added in the October 2010 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in my experience if you have problems with MotoDev Studio and you go to the forums to ask for help about the most useful reply you'll get is "works for me". Whereas standard Eclipse + plugins worked fine "out of the box".

Not very scientific though, I know.

Comment: I don't have problems with MOTODEV (at least at this point) I was wondering should I even bother, or what cool features it has that will make me to switch, but it looks that I would have to just try and find out

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment before. Looks like you figured it out though.

Answer (score 16):

I'm the product manager and tech lead for MOTODEV Studio, so let me jump in and try to help.  Sorry about the delay, I wasn't aware any conversations about MOTODEV Studio were occurring on StackOVerflow.  I'll make a point of following the conversations here as well.

MOTODEV Studio is a branded version of the IDE.  It is *not* an RCP application.  We integrate the Google ADT plugins into the Eclipse Core along with CVS, SVN, and Mylyn.  You will need to add connectors for your specific backends if you use Mylyn as there are way to many choices for us to bundle all of them.  We support Studio through our discussion boards at http://developer.motorola.com and if you visit, you won't see my teams' responses being "it works on my machine".

The next version of MOTODEV Studio comes out next week (~March 23). It will install as a single application and (despite what Fred suggests) you can also use the Eclipse update mechanism to install the Studio plugins into an existing Eclipse shell.  We've also added support for 64-bit VMs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.  Linux support is tested on Ubuntu and Fedora, but it may or may not work on others.

In addition to the Google ADT plugins, we add our own features, as DroidIn mentioned.  Some of these you may find useful and others you may not.  We're not in competition with Eclipse or Google on any of this--I and my team are committers and leaders on Eclipse OSS projects and we work with the Google tools team on joint efforts.  If you like MOTODEV Studio, we'd love to hear from you and find ways to improve it. If it's not your cup of tea, that's fine, too. Let us know if there's anything we can do to change your mind.

Comment: Thank you Eric. Looking forward to update, just like I said - I would install it and use it just for the sake of additional features but only if it comes as plugin. And since you are saying it will be then for sure - I'll give it another try

Comment: Glad to hear MOTODEV studio can now be installed at a plugin.

Comment: Eric Cloninger I must say Hats off to you. You have done a really fab job love you all team. love you great great great work done. It very very comfortable environment and its like all things present at my desk no need to go to others desk and ask for things :) wow love you

Comment: @Aizaz - Thanks for the kind words. I hope we've been able to help you write some great apps.

Comment: Dear friend are you on twitter? I want to follow you for sake of updation and I also like to follow great devs who make others life easy. you can also send me a message on twitter https://twitter.com/#!/mr_aixo

Comment: I think I have found some bug or I am probably doing something wrong. I wrote Implements and then write onTouch then ctrl+enter but it did not give me any suggestion. I went to developer.android.com and then imported android.view.View.onTouch... and then it worked...

Comment: Would it be possible to release as just plugins to standard Eclipse?  I use Eclipse for lots of things, not just Android, and I don't really have much interest in installing and maintaining 2x Eclipse instances across all my machines,

Comment: FYI, it would be very useful to add that information to your website.  I went to check it out, and left the site thinking that I'd have to install Motodev as a full app, not just a plugin.  The full app isn't really interesting.

Comment: @JamesMoore. See my comment above. There is an install guide at http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Installing_MOTODEV_Studio_for_Android/#Installing_MOTODEV_Studio_as_Plugins

Comment: @EricCloninger not related to this question but I tried to login into MotoDev and went out of the way to try your Captcha for 10 times but it does not work

Comment: @darkcrow I assume you are talking about the registration page. I am having the same problem. I'll alert our web team. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8):

All right. Looks like these days man has to do everything himself. So here it goes: My main beef with MOTODEV that there's no way (or at least no easy way) to install it as a plugin. The install contains full Eclipse + MOTODEV studio stuff. For me it's a big turn-off since I mix my development and can work on very different projects at the same time. And I use "Pulse" to maintain my favorite set of plugins across multiple machines.

- Said that - first feature I really liked was "snippets" - ability to insert pre-cooked pieces of code such as Toast, for example. Code-completion on steroids, very handy.
- Then you can browse SQLLite db - something you cannot do OOB with Google plugin.
- The emulator is built-in, that's cool or is it? I use 2 monitors and I like to have emulator outside of IDE, so - no big deal
- There's handy localization editor in MOTODEV, allows you to edit all your string values in one place
- More features but these are tight to the browser - again, no big deal
- And it retains all Google plugin stuff so you get extra without loosing anything

So as I said in the beginning - I will use it if only they provide me with way of installing it as plugin

Comment: Your main point, about the lack of a plugin, seems to have changed. Have you tested that? Personally, I only downloaded the full studio, so I can't say. And your third bullet point has also changed, you can now specify which emulator (the normal detached one, or the one inside the studio) you want when you run your application. That being said, I'm not even sure that last one was ever a problem. As far as I can remember, detaching panes as standalone windows has always possible in Eclipse (depending on where you click, that functionality is in your R-click context-menu).

Comment: I don't see anything on their website that talks about how to install as a plugin - what am I missing?

Comment: @JamesMoore To install as plugins, you can use an update site or download the full plugin archive and use as a local .zip file.  Both scenarios are described at http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Installing_MOTODEV_Studio_for_Android/#Installing_MOTODEV_Studio_as_Plugins

Comment: Got it.  May I suggest you guys make some changes to the website?  It's not really clear what you get when you install the plugin, since the list of features includes stuff that we already have with the normal Google Android + Eclipse dev environment.  Also, you really need to ditch the 'must sign up for an account' thing to install the plugin.  Reviewing the feature list doesn't really make me want to run out an install the plugin (what's so great?), and requiring an account signup moves you down to something like #87 on my list of things to seriously check out this month.