# Is MOTODEV faster than the Android Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator

I am running the Android SDK inside a Windows XP VM in VMWare. As such, the Android Emulator takes forever to boot...

I have recently heard of another emulator -- the MotoDev. For those of you who tried both, could you tell if the MotoDev has any **speed** advantage over the standard Android Emulator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the Product Manager for MOTODEV Studio.  There is not a separate emulator inside Studio, but rather another view of the existing emulator process that is displayed inside an Eclipse View. It's no faster than what you already have and depending on which transfer mechanism you use (native window vs. VNC), it could be up to 20% slower (native window is faster for Windows and Linux).

Now, as for why your emulator is taking forever...

The first time you start an emulator image (i.e. "AVD"), it has to recreate the entire target filesystem on your local disk. Subsequent launches will take less time.

If I understand correctly, you're letting the Android emulator pretend it's running its' file system through QEMU (Arm Emulator) inside a Windows XP pseudo-file system (VMWare Disk Image) that's running on whatever host operating system you have (your OS).  That's a lot of file system manipulation going on.  If you can reduce the file system mapping, you're going to see speed improvements.  Can you map the Windows Android SDK into a real folder on your native file system?  Removing that layer of abstraction is going to speed things up.

Good luck!

Eric

Comment: Wow! I couldn't ask for a better answer. I would have given you +5 but StackOverflow only allows +1. Thank you Eric.

Comment: More on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521608/motodev-studio-vs-android-google-plugin

Comment: Hmmm... "mapping into a real folder in the native file system" is called in VMWare jargon "setting up a shared folder between the guest VM and the host". Interestingly, the only source for instructions how to do that is the Workstation User's Manual in PDF format. It would have been nice if they could provide a direct URL to a relevant section instead of having to download the entire PDF.

Comment: Additional thoughts on speeding up things by moving C:\android-sdk-windows to the (Linux) host's filesystem. Shouldn't this be true for Eclipse & JDK as well?